# how to send skinny(SCCP) message using TCP

Tags: c#, tcp, voip

I am about to develop a softphone using skinny(SCCP) protocol, i have some idea what skinny is but i couldn't find anything related to implement skinny on internet, not a single documentation is available or a developer guide.

I have captured skinny packets using wireshark. i have been trying to send skinny messages in TCP, but i couldn't figure out how to correctly send the message. I have done a lot research but couldn't find anything. i have been looking at captured packets since 3 weeks. But no success

If anyone here used skinny to build softphone, provide some stuff to which will help me to accomplish this task.

i am trying to send the message in this code, what i am doing wrong?

```
    client.Connect(serverEndPoint);

        NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();

        ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();

                int ChunkSize = 240;

                byte[] SCCP_header = new byte[16];


                    SCCP_header = new byte[12];

                    //Data length
                    temp = BitConverter.GetBytes(4);
                    SCCP_header[0] = temp[3];
                    SCCP_header[1] = temp[2];
                    SCCP_header[2] = temp[1];
                    SCCP_header[3] = temp[0];

                    //header version
                    temp = BitConverter.GetBytes(0x00000000);
                    SCCP_header[4] = temp[3];
                    SCCP_header[5] = temp[2];
                    SCCP_header[6] = temp[1];
                    SCCP_header[7] = temp[0];

                    //message ID
                    temp = BitConverter.GetBytes(0x00000100);
                    SCCP_header[8] = temp[3];
                    SCCP_header[9] = temp[2];
                    SCCP_header[10] = temp[1];
                    SCCP_header[11] = temp[0];

        clientStream.Write(SCCP_header, 0, SCCP_header.Length);
        clientStream.Flush();
```

Comment: You're trying to send KeepAliveAckMessage. For one, this is message sent by the call manager, not the phone. Two, this is not the *first* message you're supposed to be sending. The phone has to register with the call manager, enumerate capabilities etc. You have to intercept every single message that's sent by the phone and the call manager if you want to replicate how skiny behaves (provided that's actually legal where you're from). The first message should be RegisterMessage (0x0001), then the IPPortMessage (0x0002) - only then will the call manager respond (with 0x0081).

Comment: i know that KeepAliveAckMessage is not the first message to send. Even if i send wrong message just like i am doing here, the message should be recognized by wireshark as skinny packet. but what i am seeing in wireshark is a malformed TCP packet. that means i am not sending SCCP correctly.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on that. Just send the proper RegisterMessage. If you want, you can force Wireshark to interpret the message as SCCP (which should show it to indeed be a proper KeepAliveAckMessage). Those messages don't have little tags saying "Hey, this is Skinny!" - Wireshark has to *guess* the protocol (based on port and perhaps some "significant" content). Sending one message that's completely unexpected at that point isn't going to help. Or, instead of forcing decode as skinny, just compare the whole TCP payload on the packet - it should be the same as the real one.

Comment: so you think there is nothing wrong in the code? i am doing it the right way and i just need to send messages in proper manner?

Comment: Nothing that would prevent it from working in the happy case. The code does send a message that should be valid SCCP (if it were sent at the right time by the server). And of course, you only want to "flip" the bytes if you're on a little-endian architecture (`BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`), but few applications care about that...